# How to link targets with instanceid as input parameter with an automation document for AWS maintenance window?

Tags: aws-ssm

Sorry for the long question but I wanted to be very specific.

I have 1 SSM automation document that has 1 input parameter, Instanceid which is a string of instances that tells the document on which instances the document will be executed.
I want to create a maintenance window  using this automation document as a task. I would like to link my instances selected as targets via a resource group and pass these instances to the document. When I'm assigning the task, at the end, I have to fill the Instanceid parameter but I don't know how to link my previously selected targets. If I do this manually using the "Resource groups >> Execute automation" section, it has an option that assing my targets to the Instanceid parameter so it gets linked. But for some reason I can't do this in Maintenance windows. Any ideas on this?